# How best way in JavaScript to do return promise in object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, browser

In this part of my code that is to try to identify if it is CPF or CNPJ before and already returns whether it is valid or not, I needed the result of the Validate () function to return to the {valid: true} object but it only returns {valid : Promise {}}, I tried to put async and await but the same result. :-(

He does not expect the promise. I tried *promise.resolve(Valid (number, type))*, but the return is <promise>.

Any suggestion?

```
function cpfcnpj (doc){
    let valid = false,
        number = doc.toString().replace(/\D/g, ''),
        masked = false,
                type = number.length === 11 ?
            'CPF' : number.length === 14 ?
                'CNPJ' : false

    if (type === 'CPF') {
        masked = number.replace(
            /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/,
            "$1.$2.$3-$4"
        )
    }
    if (type === 'CNPJ') {
        masked = number.replace(
            /^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})/,
            "$1.$2.$3/$4-$5"
        )

    }

    function Valida(number, type)
        valid = true;

        let Soma = 0, Resto;

        if (number == "00000000000") valid = false;

        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(number.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
        Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

        if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0;
        if (Resto != parseInt(number.substring(9, 10))) valid = false;

        Soma = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(number.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
        Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

        if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0;
        if (Resto != parseInt(number.substring(10, 11))) valid = false;
         
        return valid
    }

    return {
        type: type,
        valid: Promise.resolve(Valida(number, type))
                    .then(valid => { return valid }),
        number: number,
        masked: masked
    }
}


console.log(cpfcnpj('123.456.789-01'));
console.log(cpfcnpj('123 456 789@12'));
console.log(cpfcnpj('11.911.119/0001-9'));
console.log(cpfcnpj('11.9s11.1d19%0001&9'));
```

RETORNO:

```
{
  type: 'CPF',
  valid: Promise { <pending> },
  number: '12345678901',
  masked: '123.456.789-01'
}
{
  type: 'CPF',
  valid: Promise { <pending> },
  number: '12345678912',
  masked: '123.456.789-12'
}
{
  type: false,
  valid: Promise { <pending> },
  number: '1191111900019',
  masked: false
}
{
  type: false,
  valid: Promise { <pending> },
  number: '1191111900019',
  masked: false
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Promise` at all?  Why not just `valid: Valida(number, type)` ?

Comment: I would like put Valida() in a external module if is possible to structure a multi files codes

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that?  Have you attempted that and encountered a different problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case of overengineering gone awry.  There's no reason to use a `Promise` here, because there's no asynchronous operation taking place.  Just set the value in your return object with the result of your function:

```
return {
    type: type,
    valid: Valida(number, type),
    number: number,
    masked: masked
}
```